# Using an array command with `docker-compose up` is not working while a string command works

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, containers

This does not work with `docker-compose up`

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"

services:
  vscode:
    restart: always
    image: codercom/code-server:latest
    command: ['--auth none']
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

shows the following error:

```
[2023-02-04T15:08:24.628Z] error Unknown option --auth none
```

while using a string as the command works:

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml 
version: "3.8"

services:
  vscode:
    restart: always
    image: codercom/code-server:latest
    command: --auth none
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

the container build file: https://github.com/coder/code-server/blob/bbf18cc6b0e50308219e096d24961d10b62e0479/ci/release-image/Dockerfile

More interested in how these two similar commands are different

Comment: You have a syntax issue; `--auth none` is two arguments, not one, so you need to write `command: ["--auth", "none"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
You have a syntax issue; --auth none is two arguments, not one, so you need to write command: ["--auth", "none"] – 
larsks
```

Thanks @larsk!